Trying to get full purchase price for an inappurchase on Cordova Android
I have a Cordova app that uses the plugin cordova-plugin-inapppurchase-2 (which is forked from cordova-plugin-inapppurchase) to handle subscription in app purchases on Android.  My subscriptions have 7-day free trials.  When I call the plugin to get the price of the subscriptions, it's returning "FREE" - not $9.99 as it should.
(The plugin does return the correct $9.99 price if the user has already done a free trial.  Also the plugin is returning only one entry, not one for the trial period and a second one for the full price.  I realize SkuDetails is deprecated but that's what the plugin uses.)
I see an additional parameter on the SkuDetails object originalPrice.  I'm hoping this is the correct original full price of $9.99.
Does this sound like the right parameter to get the full, non-discounted price?  Anyone successfully modified this Cordova plugin?
Thanks!  - Jon
